# Problems in FQL query with multiple source_id

Tags: ios, facebook-fql

i'm trying to query :

`SELECT source_id,created_time,post_id, actor_id, message, comments.count, likes.count, attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id in (xxx,xxx,xxx)` but i'm keep getting results only for the last `source_id` in the 'in' parenthesis. i even changed their order and surprisingly i'm getting again the last one (the new last one).

if i query them separately i get the results i need.. but together ....

anyone ever stumbled across this problem ?

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: The `stream` table is very finicky. You may be up against the Facebook internal limits. Try adding `LIMIT 200` to the end of your query and see if that helps.

Comment: i just tried adding LIMIT 200 at the end but it returns an error error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2
  }

Comment: apparently it does return other posts from other groups but marks them all with the last source_id hahaha.... anyone has a clue why ?

Answer (score 2):

You should try Graph API instead:

```
?ids=24709128407,9011625258&fields=posts.limit(10).offset(0).fields(message,picture,link)
```